# How to access the elements of an associative array in javascript passed from php in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

So what I'm doing is that I'm echoing a multidimensional array from a php file called by an ajax function.

This is what the array in the php file looks like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [username] => klara
        [lev] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [username] => mira
        [lev] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [username] => coursera
        [lev] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [username] => chang
        [lev] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [username] => jack
        [lev] => 3
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [username] => elon
        [lev] => 4
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [username] => musk
        [lev] => 7
    )

)
```

My Ajax success function looks as follows:

```
success: function (response) 
{ 
    alert("response="+response);
    var array_length = Object.keys(response).length;                
    alert("array length="+array_length);

    alert("response[0][0]="+response[0][0]);


}
```

So the output is as follows:

```
response=[{"username":"klara","lev":0},{"username":"mira","lev":0},{"username":"coursera","lev":0},{"username":"chang","lev":2},{"username":"jack","lev":3},{"username":"elon","lev":4},{"username":"musk","lev":7}]
array length=204
response[0][0]=[
```

So what is happening is that "array length" is getting the length of the response instead of the number of rows and if I put a for loop and try to extract the elements then it extracts every single character in the response.

So how should I get the number of rows in the response and how should I get the values of username. That is, I wish to get the number of rows as 7 and extract the names "klara","mira",etc. How should I do it? I'm really new to this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: you have a single array and each array element is a javascript object with properties `name` and `lev`. Use object notation to access them ...while iterating array and don't use  `Object.keys()` on an array

Comment: make sure to set `dataType:'json'` on ajax request also

Comment: Also be sure you are using `json_encode()` on the php array...javascript can't read var dump of php array

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the string to JSON Object.

```
    response = JSON.parse(response)
    alert("response="+response);
    var array_length = Object.keys(response).length;                
    alert("array length="+array_length);

    alert("response[0][0]="+response[0][0]);
```

Comment: no need to parse yourself when you set proper dataType and array element objects have no property `[0]`

Comment: Hi @Vladu Ionut thank you very much for the reply...I tried what you suggested and the output I got for the array length is indeed 7 but for response[0][0], I got the output as undefined..any ideas why?

Comment: @KlaraNewbie for exact same reason I mentioned above ... the array elements are objects not arrays in javascript

Comment: @charlietfl Oh okay, so how should I work around this?

Comment: Read the linked answer/tutorial...you need to iterate the main array and access each **object** within that loop

Comment: So i tried it and I get this error : `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data` This error is on the line `response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: Okay I found it...`dataType:'json'` is causing the error